# On activity result for camera intent not working in android 2.36

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to get an image from a camera using on activity result. It is working properly on android 4.2. But I can't get the image from android 2.36.

Can anyone please help me?

**Part of source code is attached below:**

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            try {
                if (requestCode == 2) {// image from camera
                    photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                    selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    photo = decodeUri(selectedImageUri);
                    test.setImageBitmap(photo);
}
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                    getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;

            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                    break;
                }
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                    getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            if (requestCode == 2) {// image from camera
               if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(mUri, null);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            try {
                mPhoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                        .getBitmap(cr, mUri);

                Bitmap useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mPhoto,
                        mPhoto.getWidth(), mPhoto.getHeight(), true);
                test.setImageBitmap(useThisBitmap);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    resultCode + "" + "=" + Activity.RESULT_CANCELED,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this line is not needed:

```
photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```